# Evaluating this limit - help

Tags: calculus, limits

Let

$g_n(x) = $

\begin{cases} 
      \hfill x^n \sin(\frac{1}{x})    \hfill & \text{ if} \space x \neq 0 \\
      \hfill 0 \hfill & \text{if} x= 0 \\
  \end{cases}

Then why is $g_2'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g_2(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} x \sin(\frac{1}{x}) = 0$

Should this not be undefined due to the $\frac{1}{x}$ in the $\sin$ term?

Comment: Forget the limit. Simplify $g_1(x)/x$.

Comment: I am brain dead, thanks @FamousBlueRaincoat -_-

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat I have edited my question with another, if you wouldn't mind looking

Comment: Okay, now *recall* what a limit is. It is *not* plugging in $x=0$.

Comment: Is there some theorem I could use to evaluate this?

Comment: Yes: Squeeze theorem (aka squeeze lemma)

Comment: possible duplicate of [$\lim x \sin (1/x)$, when $x \to 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515357/lim-x-sin-1-x-when-x-to-0)

Comment: Thanks, thought so. It's been so long since I've used it though.