# Limit with sandwich theorem: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(x\sin(1/x)+x\cos(x)\right).$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(x\sin(1/x)+x\cos(x)\right).$$

I don't know how to solve it and I have just one thought in my mind, maybe I can solve it with sandwich theorem but I don't know why, can you tell its cause and solve this question?

Comment: Hint. Note that $\sin$ and $\cos$ values belong to $[-1,1]$.

Comment: You only need sandwich on first term of the sum, since second term goes to zero.

Comment: So how can we apply to first term to sandwich theorem?

Comment: You can find a few posts on this site about the first term [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim%5Climits_%7Bx%5Cto%200%7D%20x%5Csin(1%2Fx)%24&p=1). For example: [$\lim x \sin (1/x)$, when $x \to 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/515357).

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from $-2|x|\le x(\sin\frac{1}{x}+\cos x)\le 2|x|$.

Comment: Why do we apply sandwich theorem to x.cosx? Also why are they between -2|x| and 2|x|? Can you explain it clearly?

Comment: @Atakan Treating the terms separately is optional, since $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos x$ exists, but I decided to make the entire proof succinct. The limits follow from $\sin\frac{1}{x},\,\cos x\in [-1,\,1]\implies\sin\frac{1}{x}+\cos x\in [-2,\,2]$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Note, that for every $ \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$|\sin \alpha + \cos \beta| \leq 2$$

Comment: Where does this formula come from?

Comment: @Atakan From the triangle inequality.

Comment: @J.G. Yes I know this but I care why we are using this,this is important for me

Comment: @Atakan Because if $f\to 0$ and $g$ is bounded, $fg\to 0$ by the sandwich theorem, and in this case we can take $f=x,\,g=\sin\frac{1}{x}+\cos x$.

Comment: @J.G. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Both $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ can have values in the range [-1,1].

Therefore:

$-2x=(-1)x+(-1)x\leq x\sin(\frac1x)+x\cos x\leq x+x=2x$

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation

Comment: Having a look at "J.G."s answer I see that I made a mistake: I assumed $\lim_{x\to 0+}$ instead of $\lim_{x\to 0}$ so I wrote $x$ instead of $|x|$.

Comment: no problem I get it what you mean